# Как привести указатель на базовый класс к указателю на наследник?

Tags: c++, указатели, наследование, виртуальная-функция, приведение

Есть 3 класса: родительский Pair, и два наследника Money и Complex. По заданию нужно завести три указателя на объекты Pair, и затем с помощью них показать весь функционал Money и Complex. По ходу программы с помощью `p1=dynamic_cast<Money*>(p1)` делаю преобразование, но для p1 все еще недоступны методы класса Money. Как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Pair * p1 = new Money;
Pair * p2 = new Complex;

Money * m = dynamic_cast<Money*>(p1);
m->ФункцияMoney();
```

Примерно так. А вы пытаетесь привести указатель на `Pair` к указателю на `Money` явно, а потом неявно снова опускаете его до указателя на `Pair`. Понятно, что от хождения по кругу толку нет...